AEM 6.5 unable to pass custom variable through sightly to Java Use API
I have a template like below:
<sly data-sly-test="${clientlibDefer}">
    <sly data-sly-call="${clientlibsDeferred.js @ categories= 'testCategory', identifier='testIdentifier', loading='defer'}"/>
</sly>

The model that processes is https://github.com/nateyolles/aem-clientlib-async/blob/master/demo/ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/clientlib-async/sightly/templates/ClientLibUseObject.java, exact code. I extended it to also add the identifier but it keeps throwing null. How to fix it? I tried to get it using resource but no object in the model seems to have this custom value

When doing:
data-sly-call="${clientlibsDeferred.js @ categories= 'testCategory', identifier='testIdentifier', loading='defer'}

you are actually invoking a template named js in the template file defined by clientlibsDeferred (most likely https://github.com/nateyolles/aem-clientlib-async/blob/master/demo/ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/clientlib-async/sightly/templates/clientlib.html#L41-L50):
<template data-sly-template.js="${@ categories='Client Library categories',
                                    loading='Accepts async and defer',
                                    onload='JavaScript to run for async and defer',
                                    crossorigin='Accepts anonymous and use-credentials'}">
    <section data-sly-test="${request.getResourceResolver}"
             data-sly-use.clientlib="${'/apps/clientlib-async/sightly/templates/graniteClientLib.html'}"
             data-sly-call="${clientlib.include @ categories=categories, mode='js', loading=loading, onload=onload, crossorigin=crossorigin}"
             data-sly-unwrap>
    </section>
</template>

That, in turn, will call the include template from clientlib (located in /apps/clientlib-async/sightly/templates/graniteClientLib.html - https://github.com/nateyolles/aem-clientlib-async/blob/master/demo/ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/clientlib-async/sightly/templates/graniteClientLib.html#L26-L33):
<template data-sly-template.include="${@ categories='Client Library categories',
                                         mode='optional: JS or CSS, case-insensitve',
                                         loading='optional: JS async or defer',
                                         onload='optional: JS to run for async and defer',
                                         crossorigin='optional: accepts anonymous and use-credentials'}"
    data-sly-use.clientlib="${'apps.clientlib_async.sightly.templates.ClientLibUseObject' @ categories=categories, mode=mode, loading=loading, onload=onload, crossorigin=crossorigin}">
${clientlib.include @ context='unsafe'}
</template>

This is the code that will instantiate the ClientLibUseObject and pass the parameters and, as you can see, the identifier is not passed along on this chain.
You could skip the chain and instantiate the ClientLibUseObject yourself (passing the identifier), then call its include method.
